# I changed my password for my Google account, now Pokemon Go won't authenticate

Tags: pokemon-go

I recently had a security attack on my Google account and ended up changing my password. Now, ever since, Pokemon Go fails to authenticate. I have tried numerous suggestions found here and elsewhere with no luck. I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling, but still have had no luck. What can I do? Whenever I log in with my Google account, I fail authentication, but I can log in just fine with other accounts that I have not changed passwords for.

Comment: Could you please state what the "numerous suggestions I have tried" are? We don't know what suggestions you tried and thus might suggest one you already tried.

Comment: one of the many downsides of using google accounts for everything!

Comment: Interesting, I changed my password recently too and never had to do anything with the game. Can you log into your email on the device? What type of device are you playing on?

Answer (score 7):

If a 3rd party authenticated service fails after a password change, it usually is because they're not aware you changed your password on the 3rd party. Try logging in with your old Google password. If you get in, fully sign out and back in again. If you fail to get in with your old, try your new password again.